# Migrate from web.config to .htaccess in an Angular/Codeigniter project

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, web-config

We have a Codeigniter project which contains of two parts. The front-end that is built on Angular and the backend (API). All Angular-code is in /app/ and CI's controllers and configurations are in the /_api/ folder. The base for the webapp is in the "start"-controller.

We're trying to migrate web server from IIS to Ubuntu 16.04 and started running into problems since we haven't used our .htaccess file before. Now we only end up on CI's 404-page wherever we try to go.

Here's the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
          <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
          <match url="api/*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="js" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/api/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite CI Index 2">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|eot|woff|ttf|svg|php" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/start/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <caching enabled="false"></caching>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <!-- In case IIS already has this mime type -->
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay! The problem wasn't really the .htaccess-file mainly. The biggest problem was the move from a Windows based web server to a Linux based one. We figured out that we had to rename all of our CI-controllers and models to start with capital letters.